# HBase Shell Logging

Tags: shell, logging, hbase, hbase-shell

When using the HBase shell, I'm getting a great deal of logging, including INFO and DEBUG messages. While this is interesting in terms of learning HBase internals, it is quite verbose and can bury the output.

I've tried changing the logging levels in a number of different ways, including as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16738364/how-can-i-suppress-info-logs-in-an-hbase-client-application), and while some of the warnings do disappear, I continue to get a large number of INFO and DEBUG messages, i.e.:

```
18:50:49.500 [main] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.5-1392090, built on 09/30/2012 17:52 GMT
18:50:49.516 [main] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:host.name=ip-10-234-8-223.ec2.internal
18:50:49.517 [main] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:java.version=1.7.0_65
18:50:49.517 [main] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
```

Besides $HBASE_HOME/conf/log4j.properties, I've tried running the shell outside the $HBASE_HOME/bin/hbase shell-script. Even setting log4j.rootLogger=OFF doesn't seem to help. Attempting to use `Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.WARN);`, per the above link, did not work either.

Are these messages being emitted by a JRuby logger? Are they returned as text to the shell by other components?

Comment: I am also getting this and its really annoying. Can someone suggest a way to remove it permanently

Answer (score 0):

Edit and adjust the log levels in "log4j.properties" file which is in "hbase/conf/" folder.