# why does HRegionServer in HBase2.0.0 crash?

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper, apache-phoenix

I have set up hbase2.0.0 on hadoop2.7.7 but when I start Hbase after few second HRegionServer crashes
I don't have this problem with Hbase2.2.2.
does anybody know what the problem is?

Comment: I would be helpful if you could provide some minimum information from the logs.

Comment: no error appears, when I start HBase with "start-HBase.sh" command in terminal I can see HRegionServer in Running Services list but after a few seconds, it disappears from the list.

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431746/hbase-shell-logging