# Java HBase API Put Hangs

Tags: java, hbase, put

I have an external Java Client that is connecting to HBase. We have loaded the data primarily through batch mapreduce: TableOutputFormat. The data has been successfully pushed to Hbasetable through that method. The Java Client has been used as a way to scan through the data and provide it through a REST API.

We have a requirement to add a Put through the REST API; however, it hangs as soon as we do a put. The same HBase Client can access HBaseAdmin object and create channels. We can run Get and Scan commands, but as soon as we run a Put command, it fails. Relevant code below

```
Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create(new org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration());
config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", props.getProperty("hbase.zookeeper.quorum"));
config.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181");
config.set("zookeeper.znode.parent", props.getProperty("zookeeper.znode.parent", "/hbase"));
confResourceAsInputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("hbase-site.xml").openStream();
InputStream hdfsResourceStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("hdfs-site.xml");
InputStream coreSiteStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("core-site.xml");
config.addResource(confResourceAsInputStream);
config.addResource(hdfsResourceStream);
config.addResource(coreSiteStream);

HConnection connection = HConnectionManager.createConnection(config);
HTableInterface putTable = connection.getTable(tableName.getBytes(), null);
try {
    putTable.put(put);
} finally {
    putTable.flushCommits();
    putTable.close();
}
```

> RESULTS: I don't know why but HTableInterface putTable = connection.getTable(tableName.getBytes(), null); only works for gets. I had to change it to the following and it worked:

`HTableInterface putTable = connection.getTable(Bytes.toBytes(tableName);`

Comment: If you add a `catch (Exception ex)` in your `try` block, and log/display the exception(s), what do you see?  _I.e._ how exactly is the Put command failing?

Comment: I put an Exception in and it just hangs. It will retry again after the timeout. I let it sit for about 20 minutes and just retried a few times.

Comment: Maybe setting verbose HBase logging using _e.g._ `Level.DEBUG` might help?  See, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16749847/4072843

Comment: were you able to resolve it ?